# cannot open "edit keyboard shortcuts"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts

I had customized keyboard shortcuts of Jupyter notebook and used it for a long time. After re-installing anaconda, I tried to edit command mode shortcuts in jupyter notebook as before. But selecting the `Edit keyboard Shortcuts` never works. :(

It only displays empty screen like below link.

(https://ifh.cc/g/NuaQE.png)

This might be helpful to solving the problem.
below messages are warnings in console when I type F12.
I think problem is related to those warnings, but hard to know how to fix it.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined
at new ShortcutEditor (shortcuteditor.js:217)
at Notebook.show_shortcuts_editor (notebook.js:472)
at handler (actions.js:79)
at Object.final_actions.<computed>.handler (actions.js:890)
at ActionHandler.call (actions.js:992)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (quickhelp.js:290)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDivElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I just want to see the pages as below so that I could edit shortcuts

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwPD5.png)

Comment: (https://ifh.cc/g/5PDlb.png) here is more details.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue (Windows 10, Firefox 69, jupyter-notebook 6.0.0). Updating jupyter resolved my problem:

```
conda update jupyter
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. sadly, after updating jupyter editing keyboard shortcut still doesnt work.